# ValueError: [u'path'] error when trying to install pysftp in python

Tags: python, windows, installation

I'm trying to install [pysftp-0.2.8](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pysftp) on my 64 bit Windows 7 system, I use 32 bit python 2.7. I also have Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Express installed.  When I run

```
python setup.py install
```

from command line, I get:

```
raise ValueError(str(list(result.keys())))

ValueError: [u'path']
```

I have tried setting

```
Visual Studio 2012 (VS11): SET VS90COMNTOOLS=%VS110COMNTOOLS%
```

in command line, but it didn't help.

Answer (score 0):

When I try to install this package, it fails on the PyCrypto dependency. Everything else appears to install correctly. PyCrypto requires Visual C++ 9.0, according to the error message I receive. Instead of messing with that, I just downloaded a pre-made installer for PyCrypto from here:

- http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/modules.shtml#pycrypto

Once that's installed, you should have all the required dependencies. I was able to import pysftp after doing that.